# php: writing a curly parser

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, php-5.4

I found this idea of curly parser online and I want to further develop it. The original parser is made for passing youtube.

```
class curly 
{
    /**
     * Replace the macros in an input string
     * @param string $input
     * @return string
     */
    public function replace ($input) {
        //return preg_replace("/\{{2}([a-z]+\|.+)\}{2}/Ue",'$this->_replace("\\1")',$input); // original
        return preg_replace("/\{{2}(([a-z]+\|.+)|([a-z\_]))\}{2}/Ue",'$this->_replace("\\1")',$input);
    }

    /**
     * Run the replacement code on a given macro string
     * @param string $input
     * @return string
     */
    private function _replace ($input) {

        print_r($input);

        list ($name,$params) = explode("|",$input);

        if (method_exists($this,$name)) {
            return $this->$name($params);
        }else{
            if($input === 'email_compnay') return 'company@example.com';
                else if($input === 'email_personal') return 'personla@example.com';
        }

        throw new Exception ("Unrecognised macro: {$name}.",500);
    }

    /**
     * Replaces a YouTube curly
     * @param string $params
     * @return string
     */
    private function youtube ($params) {
        parse_str($params);

        // set defaults
        if (!isset($id)) { $id = "ykwqXuMPsoc"; }
        if (!isset($width)) { $width = 560; }
        if (!isset($height)) { $height = 315; }

        // output the final HTML
        return "<iframe width=\"{$width}\" height=\"{$height}\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/{$id}\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";
    }
}
```

example usage that works,

```
$curly = new curly();
$input = '<p>{{youtube|id=ykwqXuMPsoc&width=560&height=315}}</p>'; 
echo $curly->replace($input); 
// return <p><iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/ykwqXuMPsoc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></p>
```

another example that does not work,

```
$input = '<p>{{email_company}}</p>'; 
echo $curly->replace($input);
// return <p>{{email_company}}</p>
```

when it is `{{email_company}}` then it should return `company@example.com` but it gives me 
`{{email_company}}` instead...

Is it something not right in this regex?

```
"/\{{2}(([a-z]+\|.+)|([a-z\_]))\}{2}/Ue"
```

Comment: I am sorry but what are your trying to do exactly. I don't know PHP but i might be able to help with the regex if I know what are you trying to achieve exactly ?

Comment: thanks. I think I need a regex that is able to grab `email_company` or `youtube|id=ykwqXuMPsoc&width=560&height=315` from the double curly brackets. is it possible?

Comment: the current regex only grabs `youtube|id=ykwqXuMPsoc&width=560&height=315` but not `email_company`...

Comment: Is that a small `u` or an uppercase `U` in the modifiers list ?

Comment: it is an upper-case from the original code.

Comment: So why aren't you just using `\{{2}(.*)\}{2}`. It will definitely catch anything between double curly braces ?

Comment: I tested it. but i think it is to do with php as well as it won't work... :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think I need a regex that is able to grab email_company or youtube|id=ykwqXuMPsoc&width=560&height=315 from the double curly brackets. is it possible?

Yes it is possible. You can simply use this regex: `\{{2}([^}]*)\}{2}` and you can check it at this [**Regex 101 Demo**](http://www.regex101.com/r/oE4eZ8).

If for some reason you don't like this expression or as you said in your comment it did't work for you *(which confuses me why ?)* then you can modify the original expression you have posted to the following one and everything shell work fine:

```
/\{{2}(([a-z]+\|.+)|([a-z\_]+))\}{2}/Ue
//                          ^
//                          |
//                    Notice the added + sign, your previous expression only
//                    matched a single character.
```

And here is the [**Regex 101 Demo**](http://www.regex101.com/r/vB5wA3)

Comment: thank you. adding a `+` and it just works perfectly! thanks so much!

Comment: sometime I have re-occurrence of curly brackets in the string - '<p>{{email_company}} {{email_personal}}</p>`

Comment: and `'<p>{{youtube|id=ykwqXuMPsoc&width=560&height=315}}</p><p>{{youtube|id=ykwqXuMPsoc&width=560&height=315}}</p>'`

Comment: @lauthiamkok So everything works OK or you still have problems ?